# SQL Join using multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm using the version of SQL Server which comes with Visual Studio 2017 and trying to create a view by joining columns from four tables which are as follows:

**Table1:** `Employee (EmpID, EmpName, EmpContact, EmpSalary)`

**Table2**: `Customer (CustID, CustName, CustContact, CustEmail)`

**Table3**: `Orders (OrderID, OrderCustID, OrderDate, OrderStatus, OrderValue)`

`Orders.OrderCustID` is foreign key which relates to `Customer.CustID`

**Table4**: `Job (JobID, JobOrderID, JobEmpID, JobStatus, JobRemarks)`

`Job.JobOrderID` and `Job.JobEmpID` are two foreign keys which relate to `Orders.OrderID` and `Employee.EmpID` respectively.

Now, I want to perform a join which will show all records of Orders table along with matches from other tables in following order:

`OrderID, JobStatus, OrderStatus, CustID, CustName, CustContact, CustDue, EmpID, EmpName, EmpContact, Oredrvalue`

Someone please help me write the SQL Query to perform the join. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: have you googled sql and joins ? What did you find ?

Comment: http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: Is this a homework question? Show your own effort

Comment: @GuidoG: I already googled and can perform an inner join where a single table joins with two or three other. but in this case I'm having difficulty because Orders table joins with Customer and Job and then Job table joins with Employee. I can't write the whole thing in a single query. Please guide me through.

Comment: then start with showing us what you already have

Comment: @GuidoG: I have this much:

`Select OrderID, OrderCustID, OrderValue
From Orders o
inner join Customer c
on o.OrderCustID = c.CustID`

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk through each `JOIN` to figure out what to join where.  In other words, how do you get from Employees to Customers?  It's just a logical walk-through.

Here's one approach, using inner joins (basically a big intersection of sets).

```
SELECT OrderID, JobStatus, OrderStatus, CustID, CustName, CustContact, CustDue, EmpID, EmpName, EmpContact, OrderValue
FROM Job
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Orders.OrderId=Job.JobOrderID
INNER JOIN Customer
ON Customer.CustId=Orders.OrderCustId
INNER JOIN Employee
ON Employee.EmpId=Job.JobEmpID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the path. I figured it out and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out and I'm posting it here for any future reference.

`SELECT o.OrderID, j.JobStatus, o.OrderStatus, c.CustID, c.CustName, c.CustContact, c.CustDue, e.EmpID, e.EmpName, e.EmpContact, o.Oredrvalue
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Customer c
ON o.OrderCustID=c.CustID
LEFT JOIN Job j
ON o.OrderID=j.JobOrderID
LEFT JOIN Employee e
ON j.JobEmpID=e.EmpID`

I performed left join on all occasions because I need all the records from Orders table. Thanks a lot to all who responded.